# Prove that $(2n+1)(x+y+z)+6$ divides $x^3+y^3+z^3$

Tags: number-theory

> Let $n,x,y,z$ be positive integers such that $$(x-y)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-x)^2 = (2n+1)xyz.$$ Prove that $(2n+1)(x+y+z)+6$ divides $x^3+y^3+z^3$.

The original equation doesn't have $x^3,y^3,z^3$, so how can we show that $(2n+1)(x+y+z)+6$ divides $x^3+y^3+z^3$? Expanding the given equation seems to make the question more complicated, and also how do we get the $6$?

Answer (score 1):

We're given that

$$(x-y)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-x)^2=(2n+1)xyz$$

Hence

$$\frac{(x-y)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-x)^2}{xyz}=(2n+1)$$

Substitute this into the expression given:

$$
\begin{aligned}
(2n+1)(x+y+z)+6
=
\frac{(x-y)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-x)^2}{xyz}(x+y+z)+\frac{6xyz}{xyz}
\end{aligned}
$$

After expanding and simplifying, you will get to

$$\frac{2(x^3+y^3+z^3)}{xyz}$$

Which certainly does divide $x^3+y^3+z^3$ if one of $x,y,z$  is even...

Comment: If it wasn't clear before, it remains to show that at least one of the variables is even, but that should be a simple exercise...

Answer (score 1):

This is linked to a well-known identity (a standard exercise in high-school):
\begin{align}x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz&=(x+y+z)(x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-yz-zx)\\&=\tfrac12(x+y+z)\bigl((x-y)^2+(y-z)^2+(z-x)^2\bigr)\end{align}